# Yii 2 : Changing language only working after refresh

Tags: php, cookies, yii, yii2

I'm using the Yii 2 framework to build a custom app. My website is available both in english and french. Strings are being translated just fine, but I'm running into an issue when I wish to actually change the language from the UI.

Basically my website has two subdomains, one is `en.domain.com` and the other being `fr.domain.com`. If the user access one of those domains for the first time, my code detects the subdomain, sets the right language into Yii and creates a cookie to store the language code. If the user already had a cookie and access any of those subdomains, the code will use the cookie to set the language. If the user clicks on "FR" or "EN" to change the language, a JS script deletes the cookie and redirects to the other subdomain (basically the same flow of the first time he's on the website).

Now, the issue is that when the user tries to access the french (translated) version of the website **for the first time**, it doesn't work. The code is executed, the cookie is set (I can see it), but nothing is translated. However, when I refresh the page, it works just fine and everything is translated. Then if I switch between one and the other, it works well. It's always the first time (which is problematic, because when Google and users ask for the french version, it's still in english until they reload).

Here's a code snippet of my BaseController (all my controllers extends from this one, so this code is executed everytime the page loads):

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 * @package app\components
 */
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        // If no cookie
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["language"])) {

            $parsedUrl = parse_url(Yii::$app->HelperComponent->getUrl());
            $host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
            $subdomain = $host[0];

            if ($subdomain == 'fr')
                $code = "fr-CA";
            else
                $code = "en-US";
        }
        else {
            $code = $_COOKIE["language"];
        }

        Yii::$app->language = $code;
        setcookie("language", $code, time() + 31556926, '/');
    }


}
```

Any idea what could cause this strange behavior? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie will be created in browser **after receiving first response** from server. So it will never work on first request - technically not possible. It will work since second request assuming that user has enabled cookies. Please note that browsers may have cookies disabled - so your solution would not work.

Better solution would be:

1. store current language into server session (avoid using cookies completely)
2. evaluate current lag setting very early so the application will properly translate strings while processing the response (e.g. in Controller init, or [on beforeAction](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#beforeAction()-detail))

Comment: I've never seen modern browser with cookies disabled by default. And even if you find it, using session will not help you, since session ID is stored in cookie anyway.

Comment: @rob006 I did, many times - by users, not by default. But you are right - neither solution is perfect ..

Comment: If someone disabled cookies in his browser he should not expect that browser will remember his settings. Such cases should not be a reason to not use cookies, as they're extremely rare. Especially that session also uses cookies, so there is no good alternative and almost anything except static pages will not work if you disable cookies in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think the problem is from using cookies rather than sessions. You could remove cookies condition from my example and only use the subdomain part, it still does the same behavior. There's something about Yii (or the way I do it) that is wrong and I don't see why. The content is always loaded with the default language on the first load.

Comment: As a followup, I removed cookies to put sessions and... you were actually right! The cookie was never working the first time because it was created AFTER first server response. With sessions, everything works just fine on first load! Thank you.